# Book recommendation for introduction to mathematical reasoning

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

If you only had enough money to choose between these two books, which one would you recommend? I am personally  attracted to the second option,but seeing that I have experience with neither, I am not really sure!

[This book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/An-Introduction-Mathematical-Reasoning-Functions/dp/0521597188/ref=pd_sim_14_5?ie=UTF8&dpID=410saRhfNKL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR107%2C160_&refRID=075WM7XKHKCFK1SEBNZN) - *An Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning: Numbers, Sets and Functions* Paperback by Peter J. Eccles

OR

[This one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-Modern-Algebra-Linda-Gilbert/dp/0495561363) - *Elements of Modern Algebra* by Linda Gilbert, Jimmie Gilbert?

Thank you!

Comment: See here: https://www.coursera.org/course/maththink

Comment: Neither. 
I don't have anything against these two books but if you want to be introducted to mathematical reasoning there are a lots of better books written by masterclass mathematicians.

A classic is Polya, *How To Solve It*. If you want to be introduced in Algebra instead maybe you should ask specifically about this. I've studied Herstein, Lang and Artin, but surely there's something that perfectly fits you.

Comment: Alright thank you, i will look around some more.The reason why I listed the above books is because of their pervasiveness across first year university classes. As someone who is studying by and for himself,I am really just using the reading lists of courses as a guide as to what to get (for as little as possible).for example : http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/courses/mathematicswithbusinessandmanagement3yearsbsc/course-unit-spec/?unitcode=MATH10111

Comment: I agree that links might be a useful addition to the question. But the readers should be able to know what a post is asking without having to follow link to external sites. (Not to mention possible link rot.) This is why I have [added names of the two books](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1654327/revisions) to your post.

Comment: Of the two, I've seen only the book by Eccles, with which I have a passing acquaintance. It seems reasonably good. I would also encourage you to have a look at *Journey into Mathematics* by Rotman, which is intended for people who have been through the typical non-rigorous calculus sequence. My opinion is that the best way to make a transition from non-rigorous to rigorous mathematics is to do real mathematics, not to focus excessively on logic. For some people this comes with their first analysis or abstract algebra course, but for others the newness of the material is an obstacle. Rotman's..

Comment: book discusses topics that are both interesting and accessible for someone making the transition.

Comment: Thanks David, you are everywhere ! I am using these books to understand the language of mathematics rather than do really rigorous math.I am a realist, i can tell that proper rigour in mathematics is beyond me,but at the same time i do not want to be ignorant of the rudiments to the point where i cannot even understand the language employed to describe theories (and simple proofs).

Comment: I tend to follow questions about book recommendations, so that is why I've responded to a couple of yours. My main point is that thinking that learning logic will help you write correct proofs and appreciate mathematical arguments better is a little bit like thinking that learning the mechanics of a car engine inside out will teach you to drive. Math requires people to think at much too high a level to pay much attention to the precise rules of logic they're using. From a practical standpoint, the most that formal study of logic will achieve is to be able to put names on certain logical...

Comment: ...errors. But the same thing can be achieved by having your errors pointed out to you in practical situations. It's also useful to know words like *converse*, *contrapositive*, etc. The amount of logic that is actually useful is very limited. (I am not talking about advanced mathematical logic, which is very interesting in its own right.)

Comment: I see what you mean. I will continue to look around,  I am probably going to start with Eccles and go on from there :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Neither!**

Hey there!

I want to answer your question by providing a third option: And then for a good introduction to mathematics (specifically, mathematical logic but from scratch). Mathematical logic stresses mathematical reasoning. Then, I recommend: A logical approach to discrete mathematics by David Gries and Fred B Schneider.

Thank me later!

It’s a really wonderful book that stresses understanding Mathematical logic from scratch. In fact; it’s what I myself am currently reading right now.